# Minimize distance of LP solution to a given vector

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am solving for a regular LP problem

$max$  $c^T.v_1$

$s.t.$

$A.v_1=b$

$lb<v_1<ub$

let $v_2$ a given known vector of the same size than $v_1$.

I would like to obtain the $v_1$ solution vector such that the distance to $v_2$ is minimal i.e. $|v_1-v_2|$ is minimal.

I am wondering how can I formulate the problem and implement it in Matlab.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: (1) What happens to the original objective $\max c^Tv_1$? (2) Euclidean distance is quadratic so that would need a QP solver. (3) Rectilinear distance can be minimized as LP.

Comment: (1) the idea is to have a bi level LP maybe. In a way that $v_2$ constrains $v_1$ (2) Isn't there a way to minimize the taxicab nomr and keep it LP? (3) good to know.

Comment: This is a typical bi-objective optimization problem. Put the norm as penalty in the objective function with some weights. @ErwinKalvelagen is right: ||||_2 norm will bring you to a QP (or a conic quadratic problem), whereas a ||||_1 or ||||_inf will provide you an LP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm should do what you want.

**Step 1**

Solve
$$\begin{align}
 \min \> & z_1 = \sum_i (d_i^+ + d_i^-)\\ 
            &d^+ - d^- = v_1 - v_2\\
            &Av_1=b\\
            &\ell \le v_1 \le u\\
            &d^+, d^- \ge 0 
\end{align}$$
and record the optimal objective value $z^*_1$.

**Step 2**

Solve

$$\begin{align}
\max\> & z_2 = c^Tv_1 \\
       & z^*_1 = \sum_i (d_i^+ + d_i^-)\\ 
            &d^+ - d^- = v_1 - v_2\\
            &Av_1=b\\
            &\ell \le v_1 \le u\\
            &d^+, d^- \ge 0 
\end{align}$$

Notes:

- $d^+,d^-$ are vectors of non-negative variables (same size as $v_1,v_2$).
- LPs cannot handle $<$, $>$ inequalities. They have to be $\le$,$\ge$.

Comment: Thanks! It actually worked. I even did it one step, I have minimized for the sum of the deltas. Thanks a lot for the help!